# ListView remove selection on open

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have an android app and the main activity has a list view in it, and when I open the app it looks like this. The first item in the list view appears selected. How can I get rid of this?

[image]

So it just looks like this when it is opened.

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use `listView.setItemChecked(-1, true);` ?

Comment: @joao2fast4u I am not sure where you want me to put that line of code? And not sure how it could change the color of the item when it being tapped down?

Comment: put it inside `onCreate()`, after initializing your `ListView`. To remove the selector, use `android:listSelector=@null` in the `ListView` XML component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `myListView.setItemChecked(-1, true);` right after referencing/initializing your list view.

try `requestFocus` on any other view if that didn't work.